# Fill django-tables2 with "special" queryset

Tags: python, django

I'm trying django-tables2 to display some data, it looks like a nice tool, but I can't figure out how to use a queryset that uses fields from more than one model, at least not in an easy way. I built a queryset that shows data of five models, is the next:

```
resultado=Producto.objects.filter(codigobarras_producto=txt_codigo_producto).values('pk',
                                                                                        'nombre_producto',
                                                                                        'inventarioproducto__bodega_idbodega__nombre_bodega',
                                                                                        'codigobarras_producto',
                                                                                        'inventarioproducto__existencia_actual',
                                                                                        'codigoestilo_producto',
                                                                                        'precio__valor_precio',
                                                                                        'marca_id_marca__nombre_marca')
```

How can I define the columns headers and show this result on a django-table? I'm using django 1.8, python 3.4 and the latest version of djagno-tables2 available on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, the same elements that I wrote inside "values", I used them in "field" definitions of the meta class of the table.